# Unity how to come back to the gameplay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game, if the player press ESC, a menu button is displayed and if he clicks on it, he goes back to the main menu. How could I  do the following:

if he presses ESC again, while he is in this main menu, when the game is paused, he goes back to the game. When the player clicks on the button, I'm doing this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class VoltaMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void BackToGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Main Menu");
    }
}
```

How could I do the another part?

Comment: What do you mean by "the another part"?

Comment: You are now struggling with only going back to gameplay after ESC pressed again. And you are good with going to main menu scene. Am I Correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use an `onclick function` you will have to put an update function that checks if the player presses the escape buton.

```cs
// Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
       {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Main Menu");
       }
    }
```

Add this function your code and it should load scene *Main Menu*.

Comment: This will directly load the Main Menu scene when escape pressed. But that's not the case here

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to go back to gameplay after pressing ESC again

```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;
  using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
  using UnityEngine.UI;

  public class VoltaMenu : MonoBehaviour
 {

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{


}

void Update()
{ 
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        if(Time.timeScale == 1)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            showPaused();
        } else if (Time.timeScale ==0){
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            hidePaused();
        }
    }
 }

// Update is called once per frame
public void BackToGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Main Menu");
}

 void showPaused()
 { //Write code to show dailogue here
 }

 void hidePaused()
 { //Write code to hide dailogue i.e Pause menu
 } 

}
```

You have to complete hidePaused () and showPaused ()